# How to dynamically register type in go lang

Tags: go, struct, dynamic, types, routes

I'm newbie in go, actually I want to make an API with go those have dynamic route like I've done with Lumen, so the main func something like this :

```
func main() {
    posts = append(posts, Post{ID: "1", Title: "My first post", Body: "This is the content of my first post"})
    posts = append(posts, Post{ID: "2", Title: "My second post", Body: "This is the content of my second post"})

    db, err = gorm.Open(dbclass.DbDriver, dbclass.DataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Connection Failed to Open")
    } else {
        log.Println("Connection Established")
    }

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/{model}", getAll).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/{model}", create).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/{model}/{id}", getById).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/{model}/{id}", update).Methods("PUT")
    router.HandleFunc("/{model}/{id}", delete).Methods("DELETE")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
}
```

and I store the mcustm.go model file inside Models folder.

So when we want to get All of any model, we just call (example in postman) something like this :

`localhost:8000/mcustm`

that will call the getAll function then pass the `mcustm` parameter as a model name, and the getAll function something like this:

```
func getAll(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    model = vars["model"] // the model slug
    
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(model)
}
```

but that's not working at all, because the model are known as String instead of struct of Mcustm.
I've googling to solve that, and I found maybe some good solution using this approach:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

var typeRegistry = make(map[string]reflect.Type)

func registerType(typedNil interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(typedNil).Elem()
    typeRegistry[t.PkgPath() + "." + t.Name()] = t
}

type MyString string
type myString string


func init() {
    registerType((*MyString)(nil))
    registerType((*myString)(nil))
    // ...
}

func makeInstance(name string) interface{} {
    return reflect.New(typeRegistry[name]).Elem().Interface()
}

func main() {
    for k := range typeRegistry {
        fmt.Println(k)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", makeInstance("main.MyString"))
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", makeInstance("main.myString"))
}
```

but still not solving my problem, because on init() function we have to manually type for registerType the struct. If I have an array string of struct name, how can I registerType dynamically using that array ?

sory for my bad English

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go for language fundamentals like packages and viibility.

Comment: tks for your response @mkopriva, I've importing all necessary packages, when I try this `mcustm = models.Mcustm` and `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(mcustm))` that resulting models.Mcustm that mean my struct was readable on runtime. But I want it dynamic

Comment: *"If I have an array string of struct name, how can I registerType dynamically using that array ?"* You cannot create types from a string in Go, you need the registry and it needs to have access to proper Go types, *just* strings is not enough. The only way I can think of that allows you to use *only* strings would be to use a code generator, something that takes the string array and produces the registry, however this needs to be executed before compilation.

Comment: GO cannot generate types dynamically